# Angular 2 datagrid for asp.net core SPA application

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, datagrid

I have SPA application using asp.net core and angular 5 (typescript) and i'm looking for universal datagrid. I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datagrid but it is not maintained now. There are some more paid datagrids but i'm looking for open source. How do you create datagrids in Angular SPA applications

Answer (score 1):

you should try https://www.ag-grid.com/
Supporting Open Source

Answer (score 0):

For others who may find this helpful...

Clarity is a third party open source component library for angular created by VMware.  The data grid is full featured.  I have added it to the core 2.2 spa template pretty easily by following the getting started instructions on clarity.  You may need to upgrade your cli and angular version to use the newest clarity version but I found it worth it.

https://clarity.design/documentation/datagrid/structure

https://clarity.design/